# How can I use (index) to np package?

Tags: r

I have these command to computes bandwidth specification using the model
 `Y = G(XB) + epsilon`.

```
library(np)
bw <- npindexbw(formula=y~x1+x2)

summary(bw)

Single Index Model
Regression data (25 observations, 2 variable(s)):

      x1        x2
Beta:  1 0.1661524
Bandwidth:  1.031388
Optimisation Method:  Nelder-Mead
Regression Type: Local-Constant
Bandwidth Selection Method: Klein and Spady
Formula: y ~ 1 + x1 + x2
Bandwidth Type: Fixed
Objective Function Value: 0.4394019 (achieved on multistart 2)

Continuous Kernel Type: Second-Order Gaussian
No. Continuous Explanatory Vars.: 1
```

I want to get the Coeffeicnts(Beta values) only? 
I mean in `lm` command we can deal with it as a list (with $ sign)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be as simple as

```
coefficients(bw)
```

Comment: @KhuloodH. if the answer solved your problem, you should consider accepting the answer by clicking on the checkmark beside the answer.